# Please help me to understand what makes this question opinion-based

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, site-recommendation

So [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49059394/is-it-safe-to-call-a-c-sharp-function-with-a-result-of-function-as-a-parameter) was flagged as opinion-based. I asked a specific question and showed specific code to place my question into context.

Please help me to understand: how is it opinion based, and if my question is considered too opinion-based for Stack Overflow, then where can I pose this question?

It's a bit frustrating when I'm told to go to Stack Overflow, and I get flagged by Stack Overflow for asking a question not suited for the site.

Comment: Nobody could possibly figure out why you would assume it is not safe..

Comment: Side note: Consider coming up with some non-trivial code that *does not* "call a C# function with result of function as parameter". May hint on other equally valid close reason like "unclear what you are asking"...

Answer (score 16):

> I asked a specific question

No, actually, you didn't.  You asked:

> Is there a recommended away to implement `TargetStyle(Graduates(campus), Total(campus))` or is this an acceptable approach?

That's both not specific at all, and is *specifically asking for people's opinions as to what they'd recommend* and what they consider "acceptable".

This is all confirmed by the fact that the comments section is just flooded with people sharing their own *opinions*, and arguing with each other over said opinions, rather than being primarily about statements of facts.

That someone suggested that you post such a question on SO is unfortunate, as it isn't an appropriate question for the site. I don't know who suggested that you ask that question on SO, but you might consider going back to them and pointing out that SO is not the place to ask for people's opinions on a given programming practice.

Comment: Fair enough. Look around the web. _Every_ website says "Have questions? Go to Stack Overflow". It's the default "ask someone else" mechanism.  Lesson learned. Deleting question.

Comment: @RandomHandle Ya, it's unfortunate that sites dump people here. There are sites that redirect their customers here too because they can't be bothered to provide proper customer service. The misinformation certainly doesn't help anything.

Comment: @RandomHandle you go to Stack Overflow... to **search**. Asking is the last resort.

Comment: @Gimby You use a search engine to search, not SO.  If it takes you to SO, because that's where the answer is, great, if it takes you somewhere else, because that's where the answer is, also great.